# Shared cell between viewcontroller

Tags: ios, singleton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a scrollView with X times collectionViewController.

I would like to make a singleton in order to share the reusable cells between these controllers?.
Is-it possible ?

EDIT:
In fact, the cells created by one viewcontroller are not reuse by the others, how can them be shared?

Comment: I  don't understand why is this downvoted, because the question it is formulated properly. Technically isn't a good idea, but that can be explined in comments and answers, so I am upvoting, to reduce the negative impact.

Comment: You want to create a singleton of what? I can't see why you need a singleton here - you can just share the cells, can't you?

Comment: Hello, yes I want to share the reusables cells between multiple collectionView. But right now each collectionViewController have to create their own reusable cell.

Comment: Each collection view needs to maintain its own cache of reusable cells, I think what you're trying to do is at least a bad idea, if not impossible. Why do you think you  need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably isn't where I'd try to get performance first, but it still is possible.

Rather than letting the collection views manage cell reuse, you can do it yourself. Don't use `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. Instead, in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` fetch a cell from your own private pool. In `collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:`, put the cell back in your pool before the collection view lets go of it.

For the most flexible behavior, you should call `prepareForReuse` prior to reusing the cell. The default implementation does nothing, however, so it isn't strictly required, but I would do it anyway.